# Why didn't River want the doctor to look in the diary?

Tags: doctor-who

In *Silence in the Library* every time the Doctor tried to look at the book, River said:

> RIVER: Sorry, you're not allowed to see inside the book. It's against the rules.
>   DOCTOR: What rules?
>   RIVER: Your rules.

and also:

> DOCTOR: What's in that book?
>   RIVER: Spoilers.

Why didn't she want him to look in the book? I think, it is because she didn't want him to know his future as the 11th Doctor (Matt Smith) and the 12th Doctor (Peter Capaldi); but why did she not want him too look in the book?

Comment: Your answer is in the question: It's against the rules! If he reads about it that *creates fixed time* (just like reading Melody's novel did, or other written stuff from the same episode that I'm keeping deliberately vague).

Answer (score 6):

**I wrote this before the edit, or during the edit. I think it mostly still pertains.**

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you are asking. Does [this](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/River_Song's_diary) help?

> River Song kept a diary of her adventures with the Doctor. The cover was TARDIS blue and resembled the exterior of the Doctor's TARDIS. Since the diary was written from River's point of view, she didn't let the Doctor read it, teasingly saying "spoilers!" and often putting her finger on her lips.
>
> The book acted as an indicator of where the Doctor was in his personal timeline; whenever River met him, she would name events she had experienced with him to see if he had experienced them yet. The Eleventh Doctor, in his personal future, explained the purpose of the diary to her; she had no clue what it was supposed to be for until then.

And this?

> After the Eleventh Doctor reset the universe at the cost of his own erasure from existence, River temporarily gave Amy Pond her diary as a wedding present to bring him back. Later, the Doctor returned the diary to River, telling her that all the writing had returned, but he hadn't peeked; foreknowledge is dangerous.

Then there is this:

> By the time the Twelfth Doctor met River, River noted her diary was almost full and that the Doctor would know exactly how many pages she needed. It turned out to be providential, as in the middle of a dangerous scrape where River and the Doctor had tried to recover a priceless diamond, they noticed a familiar planet right before they ended up crash-landing on it: Darillium. Following the crash, Doctor decided to set in motion their long-delayed date to see the Singing Towers, a night lasting for twenty-four years which would be his very last encounter with her.

There's a lot of useful information [here:](http://www.denofgeek.us/tv/doctor-who/251606/doctor-who-things-you-might-have-missed-in-the-husbands-of-river-song)

> As you might expect from the convoluted story of the Doctor and River Song, this episode contains a lot of references to their previous adventures together. Before reading this article, it might be useful to read [our article on River's timeline,](http://www.denofgeek.com/tv/river-song/38321/doctor-who-the-life-and-times-of-river-song-to-date) which gives background information on some of the things mentioned in this episode, including:
>
> The circumstances behind the Doctor’s own marriage to River Song, which is a source of tension throughout the story.
>
> River’s augmented lifespan, which was a result of her conception aboard the TARDIS and experiments performed on her by the Silence.
>
> The points in her timeline at which she became a doctor and then a professor.
>
> River’s diary, which was gifted to her by the eleventh Doctor shortly after she regenerated into her ‘River Song’ incarnation.

There's a lot more, too much to go into now. I hope this helped a little.

Comment: Nice concise answer. In my opinion, this is one of the best story arcs- Amy, The Doctor, the Ponds and River.

Comment: @sfhq_sf - Agreed. It's got an amazing sweep. One of the best in all TV series. And thank you very much!

Comment: I think Moffett tried to 'catch lighting in a bottle again' with the Doctor, Clara and Danny Pink, but that arc turned out to be almost the exact oppsite

Comment: @sfhq_sf - "Never repeat yourself and always leave them wanting more."